# Preventing unauthorized use of a private remote repo once it's cloned to a local machine

Tags: git, security, github, github-for-mac

I'm going through *Pro Git* and one thing isn't quite clear. Let's suppose  that I have a GitHub **private repo** for a highly successful commercial app which I've made accessible to developers in my team. A developer can clone that repository to his computer but once it's on disk then he somehow quits and goes to work elsewhere, he'd still have that repo on his machine. What's to stop him from using that repo's source code in undesirable ways -- maybe selling it, or leaking it, or using it as the foundation for launching his own app, with a few custom tweaks here and there?

The most enlightening piece I could find was [this one](http://mikegerwitz.com/papers/git-horror-story). Even then, it still left the local repo exposed to misuse. All other links contained information already available in *Pro Git*, which I have, so basically I'm yet to find solutions for this sort of thing.

So how are private projects that use Git handle scenarios such as this one?

Comment: Utterly confused how this is a git problem.

Comment: I'm new to Git and all this. I'm under the impression that private repos in Github are just that -- private -- in the strictest sense.

Comment: github is a web site hosting git repos. Git has no feature attempting the impossible you are looking for. Github provides access control to information on the web site. Once it's not on the web site, not their problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A developer can clone that repository to his computer but once it's on disk then he somehow quits and goes to work elsewhere, he'd still have that repo on his machine. What's to stop him from using that repo's source code in undesirable ways -- maybe selling it, or leaking it, or using it as the foundation for launching his own app, with a few custom tweaks here and there?

Exactly the same thing that should be preventing that in any other situation: a decent contract, and (probably) your local copyright law.

Git doesn't change anything, legally speaking. What's to stop a developer working with code that only exists on a network share inside a company's VPN from copying that code onto a flash drive, taking it home, and using it in "undesirable ways"?

Comment: Oh. So apparently this is a legal problem, not a problem with the VCS. I was under the impression that there was a Git or Github method to somehow mitigate this sort of thing.

Comment: To the contrary, DVCS (e.g. git) could be claimed, arguably, to be amplifiers of this situation, as they make it typical for everyone and his pet cat to have complete history.

Comment: @Rookie, a technical solution is never enough. That's analogous to [security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), which isn't really security at all. Depending on where you live, copyright law may be sufficient protection. But having a good contract is equally important.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you all for your input.